# Can't mount device

Tags: debian, mount, usb-device

I can't mount my e-reader. Here's what I tried:

I connected my e-reader to the computer via usb. **dmesg** tells me the OS (debian 9) recognized the device and assigned **/dev/sdb** and **/dev/sdc** to it:

```
usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 2023.922301] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=15a2, idProduct=0c01
[ 2023.922306] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2023.922309] usb 1-6: Product: 623
[ 2023.922312] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Papyre
[ 2023.922315] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[ 2023.930149] usb-storage 1-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2023.930323] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[ 2024.961442] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Papyre   623              0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 2024.963410] scsi 4:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Papyre   623              0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 2024.964818] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 2024.966505] sd 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 2025.001429] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 2025.035684] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I tried to mount **/dev/sdb** with `mount /dev/sdb /media/ereader` getting this error:

```
 mount: no se ha encontrado ningún medio en /dev/sdb
```

Which roughly translates to:

> mount: no medium found in /dev/sdb

I also tried with the `-t vfat` option, and repeated the process with **/dev/sdc**, with the same result.

In case you ask, here's the output of `sg_map`:

```
/dev/sg2  /dev/sdb
/dev/sg3  /dev/sdc
```

And `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` (my own translation):

```
fdisk: can't open /dev/sdb: Medium not found
```

Output from `lsblk -f`:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL          UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
fd0                                                               
sda                                                               
├─sda1 ext4                  8110f71a-b0eb-4968-bdf2-2c398a4e056c /
├─sda2 ext4                  09be5f99-740b-4892-8607-a87d27953110 
├─sda3 ext4   linux_archivos 16a84f16-bca0-42e6-810e-34851fbcb0a1 /media/linux_archivos
└─sda4 swap                  ea2997b9-6401-424b-a5ea-487f6996c56f [SWAP]
sr0
```

Output from `file /dev/sdb`:

```
/dev/sdb: block special (8/16)
```

Output from `file /dev/sdc`:

```
/dev/sdc: block special (8/32)
```

Output from `file -s /dev/sdb`:

```
/dev/sdb: writable, no read permission
```

Output from `file -s /dev/sdc`:

```
/dev/sdc: writable, no read permission
```

Comment: So you get two USB storage devices, but no partition table, and Linux can't identify any file system. Please edit question with output of `file /dev/sdb` and `file /dev/sdc` (sometimes `file` can recognize formats the kernel can't). Last resort is `hexdump -C /dev/sdb | less` (or `sdc`), and see if you can make sense of it.

Comment: What does `lsblk -f` give you?

Comment: Please add the `-s` option to your file calls, like `file -s /dev/sdc`. You may need to run this as root, depending on permissions. Doesn't your ereader device export its empty memory card slot as `sdb`?  That would explain the "no medium" error messages.

Comment: If you want the actual error message in English (well, technically, untranslated) you can do, for example: `LANG=C your_command' instead of simply `your_command`.

Answer (score 0):

1. check common fdisk -l
2. what about sdc ?
3. don't forget to check device status simultaneously on you e-reader itself (e.g. Data transfer/Charging/Media Access or so).
4. needless to say root privilege is required

Comment: `fdisk -l` doesn't mention **sdb** nor **sdc**. Tried commands in the question for **sdc**, same results. All commands were run with root privilege. The e-reader seems to be stuck, can't even turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. At the end I discovered I was connecting my old e-reader to the SS-USB port. I changed it to the only simple USB port my laptop has and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  This doesn't sound like it would fix the problem described, but without knowing the exact hardware it's difficult to be certain.  Were you definitely getting the same symptoms that the OP had (devices created OK, then the "no medium found" error) before applying this fix?

Comment: Negative. SS vs USB 2 doesn't make a difference on my 2012 laptop with a memory stick showing all the symptoms (fdisk medium not found, lsblk -f not showing it, file -s saying no read permission)